# Regular Expression: Match word or Phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently, I use the following RegEx in my javascript to match and count words in string. 
That works perfekt with this ReEx:

**RegEx:**

```
var pickRegExp = /[^\W\d]+[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'](\w|[-'](?=\w))*/gi;
```

Keyword: *beautiful*

String: *The beautiful tree in the garden. In the garden is the beautiful tree.*

**Output:**

- The: 4
- **beautiful: 2**
- tree: 2
- garden
- in: 2

Now, I **also** want to match phrases (exactly). For e.g.

Keyword or Phrase: *beautiful tree*

String: *The beautiful tree in the garden. In the garden is the beautiful tree. The model tree beautiful is sold out.*

**Output:**

- The: 4
- **beautiful tree: 2**
- tree: 1
- beautiful: 1
- garden
- in: 2

I´m not really firm with RegExp. Do you have any Tips for me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
/\b(Beautiful tree|..*?)\b/gi
```

i.e. a logical OR between the exact match and a generic word matching regexp?

```
s = ("The beautiful tree in the garden. In the garden is " +
     "the beautiful tree. The model tree beautiful is sold out.");
result = {}
s.match(/\b(Beautiful tree|..*?)\b/gi).forEach(function(x) {
    result[x] = (result[x]|0) + 1;
});
```

gives

```
{ " ": 15,
  ". ": 2,
  "In": 1,
  "The": 2,
  "beautiful": 1,
  "beautiful tree": 2,
  "garden": 2,
  "in": 1,
  "is": 2,
  "model": 1,
  "out": 1,
  "sold": 1,
  "the": 3,
  "tree": 1 }
```

Comment: The phrase should be exactly matched. Single words the phrase in a different order or separately should be also matched

Comment: I have to come back again: How can I avoid that it matches blanks, . , ,  etc. and also the splitting of words with german umlauts ü, ä, ö. In the original regex, blanks, points and commas, were ignored and word with german umlauts were included. thanks for your help